# Mobile testing with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record a mobile app(not native one) through Jmeter or BlazeMeter proxy recorder. But as soon as I do the proxy settings in my device, the internet is not working on the device. I get a message as "err_connection_timed_out" .

Please help, I am new to Jmeter testing with mobile applications , any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First Confirm that You have installed CA certificate in mobile.

Before opening the app in mobile start the jmeter proxy server.

If both steps are followed, still you are not able get:
just delete the CA certificate installed in mobile and take CA certificate from your Jmeter and install it in your device.

Then run your recorder. It should work